Arm TF-A can not access linux kernel's virtual/physical address?
In my opinion, Arm TF-A (EL3) has higher privileges than Linux Kernel (EL1), and Secure World should be able to access all memory address in Normal World. To verify this feature, I added a new SMC call in Arm TF-A and wrote a kernel module to test it (on a Hikey960 Development Board). But the program does not run as expected that Arm TF-A stucked while accessing the memory address passed by Linux Kernel.
Here is my kernel module, which uses alloc_pages to acquire a physical address, and uses page_address converting it to a virtual address. And the module passes the physical address and the virtual address to Arm TF-A using smc #0:
static int __init smc_testing_init(void) {
    uintptr_t phys_addr, virt_addr;

    pr_info("Mmodule loaded\n");

    phys_addr = (uintptr_t) alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 2);
    virt_addr = (uintptr_t) page_address((struct page *) phys_addr);
    memset((void *) virt_addr, 'A', PAGE_SIZE << 2);
    printk("phys_addr: 0x%llx, virt_addr: 0x%llx\n", (uint64_t) phys_addr, (uint64_t) virt_addr);

    asm volatile(
        "ldr x0, =0xC8000003\n"
        "mov x1, %0\n"
        "mov x2, %1\n"
        "smc #0\n"
        :
        : "r" (phys_addr), "r" (virt_addr)
        : "x0", "x1", "x2"
    );

    __free_pages((struct page *) phys_addr, 2);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit smc_testing_exit(void) {

    pr_info("Module unloaded\n");
}

And here is the handler's code in Arm TF-A, which prints the addresses of physical address and virtual address, and access the first element of the memory address:
if (0xC8000003 == smc_fid) {
    uintptr_t virt_addr = x3;

    NOTICE("phys_addr: 0x%lx, virt_addr: 0x%lx\n", phys_addr, virt_addr);
    NOTICE("virt_addr[0] = 0x%x\n", *((uint32_t *)virt_addr));
    NOTICE("phys_addr[0] = 0x%x\n", *((uint32_t *)phys_addr));

    SMC_RET0(handle);
}

Here is the output, Arm TF-A handles the request successfully, but failed to access the memory address passed by Linux Kernel:
# insmod ./smc_testing.ko                                                                                                                                                     
[   75.259590] smc_testing: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.                                                                                                         
[   75.266682] Mmodule loaded                                                                                                                                                 
[   75.269404] phys_addr: 0xfffffc0002dc5e00, virt_addr: 0xffff0000b7178000
NOTICE:  phys_addr: 0xfffffc0002dc5e00, virt_addr: 0xffff0000b7178000
[   96.276605] rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
[   96.282741] rcu:     4-...0: (1 ticks this GP) idle=72ec/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=204/204 fqs=2592
[   96.291835]  (detected by 0, t=5253 jiffies, g=-643, q=16 ncpus=8)
[   96.298044] Task dump for CPU 4:
[   96.301287] task:insmod          state:R  running task     stack:0     pid:201   ppid:185    flags:0x00000006
[   96.311254] Call trace:
[   96.313713]  __switch_to+0xe4/0x160
[   96.317241]  printk_rb_static+0x30/0x58


Pretty sure EL3 virtual address translation is very different from EL1 address translation, so you can't pass along an EL1 virtual address and dereference it in EL3 and expect that to just work. EL3 could access non-secure physical memory if it is mapped in EL3 page tables.

@AndreyTurkin Thanks for replying. So this means non-secure memory is not mapped in EL3 page tables naturally, Is there any way to add this mapping?

It doesn't follow from my reply. Virtual address surely wouldn't "just work" because mappings are completely different. Physical address might be mapped somewhere in EL3 VA. You need to consult TF-A docs for how to deal with this (start with XLAT library)

What you call phys_addr is the kernel virtual address of the struct page.

@stark Thanks! I indeed missed this mistake... And I tried again, EL3 still can not access the "real physical memory", so I need to add the mapping anyway.

Just looking briefly at your code and phys_addr = (uintptr_t) alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 2) is definitely wrong. alloc_pages() returns a virtual address (of an array of struct page * pointers). The subsequent call virt_addr = (uintptr_t) page_address((struct page *) phys_addr); is therefore not doing what you think. Also, don't simply cast stuff to uintptr_t, it just hides errors. Do it only at the end if needed. If you changed the code after fixing this mistake, update your post with the new code and logs please.
